# Python/MySQL execute in for gives error:- TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I get the following error when I execute cursor in for loop.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql_select_query.py", line 35, in <module>
    for row in cur.execute(sql_select):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code that gives error:

```
sql_select = "SELECT * FROM T_EMP"
for row in cur.execute(sql_select):
    print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

It works well when I execute & use fetchall():

```
sql_select = "SELECT * FROM T_EMP where ID>%s"
rows = cur.execute(sql_select, [0])
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

My MySQL table schema:

```
mysql> desc T_EMP;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| CREATED    | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| EMP_CODE   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| USER_ID    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| FIRST_NAME | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| LAST_NAME  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| DEPT_ID    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| ADDR_ID    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any clue is grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMySQL [`Cursor.execute`](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute) returns an **`int`**, i.e. a number that tells the number of lines affected. It doesn't match the behaviour of [MySQLConnector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), and certainly you cannot loop over a single number using a `for` loop.

Use `fetchall` like in the other example:

```
sql_select = "SELECT * FROM T_EMP"
cur.execute(sql_select)
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

Or iterate from the cursor row by row:

```
sql_select = "SELECT * FROM T_EMP"
cur.execute(sql_select)
for row in cur:
    print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

Notice also that the DBAPI requires that you create a new cursor for each query, i.e.

```
cur = connection.cursor()
```

before each `cur.execute`.

Comment: It is better to make him understand "why?" in details and not just restate what was written inside the Question itself in some other words.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fundamentally wrong:

1- The `SELECT` statement returns data as it is but the function `cur.execute()` returns the iterator which is an integer, then using that integer in `row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]` as if it can be iterated (which clearly can't be for a simple integer, there's no first index, second index, third index, fourth index)

2- The other function `cur.fetchall()` is equal to a `SELECT * FROM table` but more complicated because it syncs with what hasn't been used yet of that data by this cursor `cur` and the code that is working for you isn't but the following part (not 100% sure so test by commenting out the other two lines)

```
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

So, the best answer would be knowing what's written above and then going back to the "classroom" if you know what I mean, or at least read how to use python cursor class, peace.